# Load a JavaScript function after everything else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a JavaScript function to be called after everything else (other JavaScript functions and CSS) runs. This function changes the CSS of the slideshow I'm creating.

I have added the function to my HTML file:

```
function loadFullSlideShow {    
  alert('If I remove this alert this would not work');
  $('#background').width('100%');
  $('#background').height("auto");
  $('#slide_area').width('100%');
  // alert('This alert ensure application of CSS with code below');
  $('#slide_area').height("auto");
  $('img').width('98%');
  $('img').height('auto');
  $('#thumb_container').width('100%');
  $('#thumb_container').height('auto');
  $('#controls').css('top', $('img').height());
  $('#caption_credit_footer').css('top', ($('img').height() + 18));
});
```

I want this function to be called after all other scripts have done loading. Surprisingly, when I make a call to the `alert` in the first line of the code, and click `OK` on the alert box, the changes in the CSS are being applied. However, when I remove the alert, the changes aren't being applied.

I suspect that when I remove the `alert` the code is executed before some of the other JavaScript code. How can I ensure that this code runs at the very end of the page load?

I've tried calling this function in many ways:

1. `$(window).bind("load", function() { loadFullSlideShow() });`
2. `$(window).on("load", function() { loadFullSlideShow() });`
3. `window.load(function() { loadFullSlideShow()});`
4. `$(function() { loadFullSlideShow() });`
5. I also tried binding this in `<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>`.

**Edit:** I am using [jPlayer Plugin](http://www.jplayer.org) for jQuery JavaScript Library.

Comment: Try placing your script at the very end of your html code.

Comment: Sounds like some other script is loading the content dynamically.

Comment: @Mysteryos I tried that too.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah, this is the case here. Because I'm using a jQuery plugin for creating the slideshow.

Comment: You need to run the function in an event that's triggered by the plugin; most plugins have hooks just for this.

Comment: Why do you set these CSS properties through Javascript? This can be done using a simple CSS file!

Comment: What is it you mean with _all other scripts have done loading_, you mean by that just the script file itself or functions that are suppose to _load_ something?

Comment: @Juhana : thank I will investigate how to do that as I'm new to jQuery. Any specific pointers you could give would be helpful.

Comment: @dbf I meant to say the function should be executed at the last, when all the functions in the other JS files are executed.

Comment: I don't understand, how my question gets two -ve marks. I've described the question well, and also showed what efforts I took in order to achieve this.

Comment: You need to tell which plugin you're using. Otherwise it's pretty impossible to say what kind of hooks it provides.

Comment: You also need to show what code you're trying to wait for to complete before you call your function.  Just relevaling the plugin isn't enough in this case.  Plus, your code is just setting CSS on normal DOM elements.  It is not clear why it has anything to do with jPlayer.  A demonstration of the problem in a jsFiddle would assure we have enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `alert()` fixed your code, then you probably have some asynchronous code running and the `alert()` causes your code to not get executed until after that asynchronous code has finished.  The only way to make your code reliably run after the asynchronous code is done is to hook into the completion function of the asynchronous code so you can know when it is done (option #6 below).  If this asynchronous code is some library, then you need to look in the documentation for that library and find a callback that you can register to know when it's done.

You haven't described what else is in your page that you want it to load after so it's impossible for us to know exactly what to recommend.

Basically, you have to organize your code into the right sequence and it will get called in the desired sequence as regular javascript (not stuff scheduled on events) is executed in the order it is parsed.  Your choices are:

1. Fix the order of your scripts in your file so they execute in the desired order.
2. Put it at the end of the `<body>` tag and it will be the last script to run.
3. Use `$(document).ready(loadFullSlideShow)` and it will run after the DOM is ready.  If you have other .ready() scripts that you need this to run after, then register this one last and it will be executed last.
4. Use `$(window).load(loadFullSlideShow)` and it will run after the DOM is ready and all images have loaded.  If there are multiple scripts with `.load()`, then register this one last and it will get called last.
5. Use a `setTimeout(loadFullSlideShow, xx)` and it will get run some time in the future.  This is generally a hack. Careful organization of your code can prevent the need to do this.
6. If you have asynchronous scripts that you want to wait until after they are done, then you will have to call your function from the completion function of the asynchronous scripts.
7. Use a `setInterval()` and poll your page waiting for certain content to be present before running your code.  This is also a hack and there are always better solutions (like registering a completion callback)
8. Use classes or ids and specify your style rules as CSS so they are always present and you don't have to apply the styles with javascript code.  Then you won't have to worry about timing at all.

Comment: Why a downvote.  I've laid out the options for the OP.  The OP hasn't provided enough information about what they want their script to be executed after to be more specific than this.

Comment: At the time of the downvote the options you laid out were exactly the sames the OP says he has tried, and in the comments it's established that the content is being loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Juhana - do you still think the answer deserves a downvote?  Is the solution not covered here now?

Comment: It's ok now, but I can't remove the downvote. If you make an edit I can do it.

Comment: @Juhana - I just added a new first paragraph and option 7.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I am new to jQuery, I will have to investigate on how to _hook_ into a jQuery function. I will report back as soon as possible. Any specific pointers on how could I get started. Thank you again.

Comment: @develkar - you'd have to show us what jQuery function you're using.  All jQuery asychronous functions offer a completion callback function you can pass as an argument.  That callback will be called when the asynchronous operation is complete.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question. I am using [jPlayer Plugin](http://www.jplayer.org) for jQuery JavaScript Library.

Comment: @develkar - jPlayer has its own `.ready()` method, but you haven't shown why that is connected to your code so I have no idea if that is what you are looking for or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying CSS with Javascript, why not use CSS? It is faster and more compatible!
If it doesn't work you should focus on fixing your CSS instead of using Javascript.

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 
#slide_area {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
}

#thumb_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#controls {
    /* Find a valid CSS way to position this, e.g. with margin. Depends too much on your HTML */
}

#caption_credit_footer {
   /* Find a valid CSS way to position this, e.g. with margin. Depends too much on your HTML */
}
```

Comment: I could not do this because, this would make changes on page load, and the jQuery plugin I'm using is loading CSS images dynamically. Should have made this clear in the question. Anyways, thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: Then use the `!important` directive: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/. Or even better: alter the CSS the plugin loads! This still is a CSS issue, not a Javascript issue.